# It is not able to display message

Tags: c

```
//program to display message using function as a parameter
#include<stdio.h>
#include<process.h>
//return name
char name_display(char *name)
{
    return *name;
}
//display name
void display(char (*display)(char *name1),char *name2)
{
    char name3;
    name3=display(name2);
    printf("name is %s",name3);
}
void main()
{
    display(name_display,"message");
}
```

Comment: Please be more detailed about what you're asking and try to show evidence of research first.

Comment: `%s` requires a `char *` or `char const *`, not a `char`. Reread the chapter in your instructional text on arrays, then the one on strings. And before posting another question, please take the time [**to read this first**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Certainly: `printf("name is %s",name3);` wants to print out a string, but `name3` is only a `char`. Either fix it like:

`printf("name is %c",name3);`

or modify your code to be:

```
char* name_display(char *name)
{
    return name;
}
//display name
void display(char* (*display)(char *name1),char *name2)
{
    char* name3;
```

ie: work with strings instead of chars.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following changes- (Take a Look at the Fix's in program)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
//return name
char* name_display(char *name) // Fix 1, when you are returning char array use char *
{
    return name; // Fix 2 (return only the name of the array, no need of *name)
}
//display name
void display(char* (*display_call)(char *name1),char *name2) // Don't use same Function name. When you look at the program again it may confuse you
{
    char *name3; // Fix 3 
    name3 = display_call(name2);
    printf("name is %s \n",name3);
}
void main()
{
    display(name_display,"message");
}
```